# Finding the column in which a specified value appears

Tags: r, apply, identify

In a numeric data frame (say "data") with n columns, I use "apply" to calculate the max value by row, then I create a new column containing that max value:

```
data[, n+1] <- apply(data[, 1:n], max)
```

But how can I add another column containing the place where the max appears (i.e. in which column number between 1 and n ?) For example, I would like to have:

```
> data
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8 Max Place
1   35   32   51   52    0   76   50   55  76     6
2    3   73    4   44   48   74   64   21  74     6
3   38   98   57   56   58   19   92   77  98     2
4   63   87   34   22   79   90   68   47  90     6
5   81   42    9   61   66   14    8   12  81     1
6   85   60   70   96   45   33   93   11  96     4
```

In the first row, max=76, appearing in the 6th column... etc. I thought of something using "which", but I don't find how to use it.

Comment: This is a duplicate: `max.col(df[1:8])` will do this for you.

Comment: Thanks. Couln't remember it...